# How to select the first one of a h4 element that is under the same element but in different depth?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For example I have this code:

```
<div class="main-element">
    <h4>Title 1</h4>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li>
            <h4>Title2</h4>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to select and use the same styling on all h4 elements but I also want to put additional styles on the first one. for example I want all h4 element's margin-top and margin-bottom to have the value of 8px, but for the first h4 element I want their margin-top to have the vaule of 0.

I've tried to use the :first-child and first-of-type selectors. for example:

```
.main-element h4 {
  color: blue;
}

.main-element h4:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

It colors all elements red instead of only the first one.

Comment: _"It colors all elements red instead of only the first one."_ - of course it does, because `:first-of-type` applies within a group of siblings. `.main-element > h4:first-of-type` - using the child combinator, this will only apply to h4 elements that are children of `.main-element`

Answer (score 0):

`first-of-type` will be true for both `h4`'s since the second one is inside a `<li>`, which makes is the first child again.

Consider adding classes to the one you wish to style

```css
.main-element .reset {
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: red;
}

.main-element h4 {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-element">
    <h4 class='reset'>Title 1</h4>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li>
            <h4>Title2</h4>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`first-of-type` always relates to the current parent, i.e it means "first occurrence of this type within this container". So your `.main-element h4:first-of-type` matches every h4 that is a descendant of `main-element` and is the first h4 in its parent.

If you want to style only the one that's a direct child of the parent, you can use the ">" selector, like:

```
.main-element > h4:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```